# JS YouTube Regex With Empty input acceptable

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I have a youtube input for the embedding code and I wish to be able to also have the user not necessarily have to input a youtube embed. But I'm stuck about how to alter my regex to accept an empty field... I have set errors if the user fails the regex and no errors if the user passes the regex, So I would imagine there would be a simple fix to the regex to accept an empty input value.

Can anybody see how I would achieve this from my code below...

Thank you for any advice.

```
function checkyoutube() {


var youtube = $("#youtubevalue").val();


//var youtubeReg =/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-+&%#=?<>()£~_\.*@$!, \r\n]{0,300}$/;
  var youtubeReg =/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;

    if(!youtubeReg.test(youtube)) { localStorage.setItem('error', 'true');
        $("#youtubefooter").text("Example https://youtu.be/12KxXnFbwbU"), $( "#youtubevalue" ).addClass( "errorclass" ), $( "#youtubevalue" ).removeClass( "noerrorclass");
                    }  

    if(youtubeReg.test(youtube)) { localStorage.setItem('error', 'false');
        $("#youtubefooter").text("URL Is Good, Thanks!"), $( "#youtubevalue" ).addClass( "noerrorclass" ), $( "#youtubevalue" ).removeClass( "errorclass");
                    } 



var youtubeB = document.getElementById('youtubevalue');

(var regex= LOTS / OF / BAD / WORDS;)'EDITED FOR STACK'
youtubeB.value=youtubeB.value.replace(regex, "****");   


};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the regex optional `?` by using a non capturing group `(?:`.....`)?`

[`^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/KzKR9N/1)

```js
var youtubeReg = /^(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?)?$/;
var strings = [
  'https://youtu.be/12KxXnFbwbU',
  '',
  'https://youtu'
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + ' ==> ' + youtubeReg.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Must it be done with regex? If not, you could simply trim the input and check if its empty, if empty then its good and if not apply regex.

See the below code

```
function checkyoutube() {

var youtubeReg =/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;

var youtube = $("#youtubevalue").val();
 //checking for length here after trimming 
if(youtube.trim().length==0||youtubeReg.test(youtube)) { localStorage.setItem('error', 'false');
    $("#youtubefooter").text("URL Is Good, Thanks!"), $( "#youtubevalue" ).addClass( "noerrorclass" ), $( "#youtubevalue" ).removeClass( "errorclass");
                } 
else{//skipped testing for regex again here
localStorage.setItem('error', 'true');
    $("#youtubefooter").text("Example https://youtu.be/12KxXnFbwbU"), $( "#youtubevalue" ).addClass( "errorclass" ), $( "#youtubevalue" ).removeClass( "noerrorclass");
}




var youtubeB = document.getElementById('youtubevalue');

(var regex= LOTS / OF / BAD / WORDS;)'EDITED FOR STACK'
youtubeB.value=youtubeB.value.replace(regex, "****");   


};
```